# make a call ajax before another call ajax ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call that is responsible for uploading (via SFTP). They are large files so I can not lock the page.
On the same page I have a search field that via ajax displays results in a table.
The problem: when I call the upload ajax everything on the screen still works, but the search ajax request only refreshes the table when the upload ends. how can i request the search ajax and display the result on the screen before the ajax upload completes?

note: all calls are asynchronous

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#idsearchall", function(){
    var valor = $(this).val();      
    updatetable(valor);
});
function ajax(options) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax(options).done(resolve).fail(reject);
  });
}
var updatetable = function(text){
    ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: ".../index.php?status=ajax",
        async: true,
        data: {mk: 4,  search: text}
    }).then( 
      function sucess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $('#tablesearchall').html(data); //Success works well               
      },
      function fail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
      }
    ).catch(function errorHandler(error) {
        console.log(error);                 
    }); 
};
$(document).on("click", "a[input-send='upload']", function(){
//**... ... ... codes to get file information
var formData = new FormData();                      
formData.append('documento[]', fileSelect[0], fileSelect[0].name);
ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: ".../transmissao.php?status=ajax&mk=1",    
    data: formData,
    processData: false, 
    async: true,
    contentType: false  
}).then(
  function sucess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var splitmsg = data.split("|");
    if(parseInt(splitmsg[0])== 1){
        var pathftp = splitmsg[1];                          
        alert('success', "info"); //Success works well      
    }
  },
  function fail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
  }                   
).catch(function errorHandler(error) {
    console.log(error);         
});});
```

[showing both calls as pending](https://mega.nz/#!9t4R1RBL!Wxl-BqvJLZ9XDIyIV77HIKqt9Xp4drxhS52lSaL_WAw)

Thank very much in advance

Comment: Do you mean the search ajax request only completes once the upload ajax request completes?

Comment: why are the ajax calls asynchronous though?

Comment: Yes, there is a queue of requests in the browser until the upload request returns, then unlocks everything.

Comment: That is not how browsers handle ajax requests. A second request can complete before the first

Comment: @djaax because ajax is asynchronous and should never be done synchronously and in fact synchronous requests are deprecated as they have always been a terrible practice

Comment: @djaax - I had to do so, because if it was sync it would hang the page and the user would not like it, haha

Comment: add a third function to .then .. https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/ and maybe .when .. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: @BrianPatterson - In my opinion, _when_ it is an attempt to sync the calls and show only one result, however, I want to parallelize things while the files go up in the background.

Comment: posted an answer to demonstrate what i mean.  will that not work?

Comment: async:false = Code paused. (Other code waiting for this to finish.)
async:true = Code continued. (Nothing gets paused. Other code is not waiting.)
did you try make ajax request async:true

* note as far as i know its by default async:true

Comment: @JehadAhmadJaghoub - I know the default is asynchronous, but I left the code to show that I am doing asynchronous, to make it clear that I do not want to synchronize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!!
The problem was in the php session

In php file:

```
//Get info Session
$user  = $_SESSION['id'];
//write and close the session to answer the request
session_write_close(); 
/***
**** here is the upload part
***/
session_start($user); //I reopen the session
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i meant in comments?   wont this work for what you are attempting?

```
$.when(
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html/',
        success: function(data) {
            alert('request complete')
        }
    }),
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html/',
        success: function(data) {
            alert('request complete')
        }
    })
).then( function(){
    alert('all complete');
});
```

Comment: I can not see how to do this using When.
Because the ajax calls are not made together, the upload call will be made first, which can take a long time to return, and at another time the search call will be made, which will start and end before the upload is completed .....
Using When I do not know if it is possible to follow this rule

Comment: I read somewhere that: 
The request will be queued only if:
There is some lock somewhere -- which can happen, for instance, if the two requests come from the same client, and you are using file-based sessions in PHP : while a script is being executed, the session is "locked", which means the server/client will have to wait until the first request is finished (and the file unlocked) to be able to use the file to open the session for the second user. https://www.quora.com/How-php-handle-multiple-request-at-same-time
Is it really the fault of the session?